# How to enhance a basic drum kit without buying

Tags: drums, drum-kits

I am currently using a basic electronic drum set which looks something like this

[image]

I would like to add a [high mid tom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom-tom_drum) & low mid top & high floor tom & splash cymbal to my set but the problem is that I cannot buy any add-ons to the drum set. What do you suggest I should do to simulate the sounds of the respective drum mentions above?

Are there any household items or items which can be easily made which sound similar to the drums mentioned above?

Comment: No answer here.  But I just hit guitarcenter recently.  A good Yamaha set with all the drums,cyms is $1000.  And the snare has multiple zones.  That's what -I'm- doin':)

Comment: do you mean to say "there are no more open trigger ports to plug into on the head unit" or "I have no money for more triggers"

Comment: I mean "there are no more open trigger ports to plug into the head unit"

Comment: is it an alesis dm5 head unit?

Answer (score 2):

About new pads and connecting them to the main unit, I would buy another module with pads or a multi pad and use the jack out > jack in to connect the two modules together.

About putting up these pads + module or the multipad to the drum stand, it is the main problem. I think you have no choice but buying additionals support / mount.

The multipad may certainly be easier to add to your kit.

Answer (score 1):

Get a MIDI to USB adapter and plug it into your computer, then use a drum kit sampler such as Native Instrument's Abby Road series or ToonTrack's Superior Drummer (which are both excellent and the latter has many sample sets.) There are many free samplers and sample sets out there as well.